# Password Generator with GUI

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt

I just finished my first GUI app, a Password Generator that can take any characters you want(I've added some default characters to make your life easier), and a password length up to 999, and some small features like copy to clipboard and clear button...

I used `PyQt5` to build my GUI and some helpful modules like `pyperclip`, `webbrowser`...

This is what the app looks like on Windows:

[image]

I used Pyinstaller to convert .py to .exe download the Password Generator.exe [here](https://mega.nz/#!wZ9yTLZB!606U33Vjx6SrMAjftZCTqI3gjOK-J2d8HLhsuZ0Fs2A)

Here's the source code:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.5.2


from PyQt5.QtWidgets import*
from PyQt5.QtCore import*
from PyQt5.QtGui import*
import random
import pyperclip
import webbrowser
import sys


class Password_Generator(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        QWidget.__init__(self)

        layout = QGridLayout()

        self.menuBar = QMenuBar()
        self.default_characters = QPushButton()
        self.characters = QLineEdit()
        self.passwordlength = QLineEdit()
        self.pl_option = QComboBox()
        self.progress = QProgressBar()
        self.generate = QPushButton("Generate Password")
        self.result = QLineEdit()
        self.clipboard = QPushButton("Copy to clipboard")
        self.clear = QPushButton("Clear")

        self.fileMenu = QMenu("File", self)
        self.clearAction = self.fileMenu.addAction("Clear")
        self.exitAction = self.fileMenu.addAction("Exit")
        self.menuBar.addMenu(self.fileMenu)
        self.helpMenu = QMenu("Help", self)
        self.source_code = self.helpMenu.addAction("Source Code")
        self.information = self.helpMenu.addAction("About Me")
        self.menuBar.addMenu(self.helpMenu)
        self.characters.setPlaceholderText("abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890$@^`,|%;.~()/\{}:?[]=-+_#!")
        self.characters.setFixedWidth(524)
        self.passwordlength.setPlaceholderText("password length")
        self.passwordlength.setFixedWidth(85)
        self.passwordlength.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.passwordlength.setValidator(QIntValidator(0, 999))
        self.passwordlength.setMaxLength(3)
        self.pl_option.setFixedWidth(58)
        self.pl_option.addItems(["Default", "8", "16", "32", "64", "128"])
        self.progress.setValue(0)
        self.progress.setAlignment(Qt.AlignHCenter)
        self.generate.setFixedWidth(125)
        self.default_characters.setFixedWidth(24)
        self.default_characters.setIcon(QIcon(r'C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Password Generator Files\file-default-icon-62367.png'))
        self.result.setReadOnly(True)
        self.result.setFixedWidth(425)

        layout.addWidget(self.default_characters, 0, 0)
        layout.addWidget(self.characters, 0, 1, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.passwordlength, 0, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.pl_option, 0, 4)
        layout.addWidget(self.generate, 1, 0, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.result, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.progress, 1, 3, 1, 2)
        layout.addWidget(self.clipboard, 3, 0, 1, 3)
        layout.addWidget(self.clear, 3, 3, 1, 2)

        layout.setMenuBar(self.menuBar)
        self.setLayout(layout)
        self.setFocus()
        self.setWindowTitle("Password Generator")

        self.generate.clicked.connect(self.generated)
        self.clipboard.clicked.connect(self.clipboard_copy)
        self.clear.clicked.connect(self.cleared)
        self.default_characters.clicked.connect(self.default)
        self.pl_option.currentIndexChanged.connect(self.numbers)
        self.clearAction.triggered.connect(self.cleared)
        self.exitAction.triggered.connect(self.exit)
        self.source_code.triggered.connect(self.get_source_code)
        self.information.triggered.connect(self.info_window)

        self.new_window = Info_Window()
        self.new_window.setWindowIcon(QIcon(r'C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Password Generator Files\Lock_closed_key_2-512.png'))
        self.new_window.setWindowTitle("About Me")


    def get_source_code(self):
        webbrowser.open(r"C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Password Generator Files\Source Code.txt")

    def info_window(self):
        self.new_window.setWindowFlags(Qt.WindowCloseButtonHint)
        self.new_window.show()
        self.new_window.setFixedSize(665, 350)


    def exit(self):
        sys.exit(app.exec_())


    def numbers(self):
        if self.pl_option.currentText() == 'Default':
            self.passwordlength.setText(None)
        else:
            self.passwordlength.setText(self.pl_option.currentText())


    def default(self):
        characters = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ1234567890$@^`,|%;.~()/\{}:?[]=-+_#!"
        self.characters.setText(characters)


    def generated(self):
        try:
            characters = self.characters.text()
            password_length = int(self.passwordlength.text())
        except Exception:
            return

        self.password = ""
        for i in range(password_length):
            try:
                characters_index = random.randrange(len(characters))
            except Exception:
                return
            self.password = self.password + characters[characters_index]
            self.progress.setValue(100)
        self.result.setText(self.password)


    def clipboard_copy(self):
        if len(self.result.text()) > 0:
            pyperclip.copy(self.result.text())
            QMessageBox.information(self, "Information", "Password has been copied to clipboard!")
        else:
            return


    def cleared(self):
        self.characters.setText("")
        self.passwordlength.setText("")
        self.progress.setValue(0)
        self.result.setText("")
        self.passwordlength.setText(None)
        self.pl_option.setCurrentIndex(0)


class Info_Window(QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QDialog.__init__(self)

        info_layout = QGridLayout()

        self.info = QLabel("Password Generator\n"
                           "Version 1.0\n"
                           "Contact Riverbank at info@riverbankcomputing.com\n"
                           "Copyright © free 2016 Riverbank Computing Limited under GNU General Public License version 3\n"
                           "Contact Me at iteleport2015@gmail.com\n"
                           "Copyright © free 2017 Salah Gfx Open Source Project\n")
        self.about_me = QLabel("My name is Salah, I'm a college student, I study computer science and mathematics, I'm also a graphic designer\n"
                               "and python programmer, I'm a self taught, I have 3 years of experience in 3D design and 1 year in coding, I wish\n"
                               " to make 3D games in the future, combining those knowledges I believe I can make it, this app is my first GUI app,\n"
                               " I used to run all my codes and scripts in the console but now it feels different how you can share your work with\n"
                               " normal people, it is just amazing and helpful, have a nice day and I wish for you a successful life.")
        self.Font = QFont()
        self.Font.setBold(True)
        self.about_me.setFont(self.Font)
        self.Hline = QFrame()
        self.Hline.setFrameShape(self.Hline.HLine)
        self.Hline.setFrameShadow(self.Hline.Sunken)
        self.Vline = QFrame()
        self.Vline.setFrameShape(self.Vline.VLine)
        self.Vline.setFrameShadow(self.Vline.Sunken)
        self.image_label = QLabel()
        pixmap = QPixmap(r"C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Password Generator Files\SLH-GFX2.png")
        self.image_label.setPixmap(pixmap)

        info_layout.addWidget(self.info, 0, 2)
        info_layout.addWidget(self.Vline, 0, 1)
        info_layout.addWidget(self.image_label, 0, 0)
        info_layout.addWidget(self.Hline, 1, 0, 1, 3)
        info_layout.addWidget(self.about_me, 2, 0, 1, 3)

        self.setLayout(info_layout)




app = QApplication(sys.argv)
window = Password_Generator()
window.setFixedSize(732, 120)
window.setWindowIcon(QIcon(r'C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Password Generator Files\Lock_closed_key_2-512.png'))
window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

The files needed [here](https://mega.nz/#!ZdFiCBaC!4X4VRZJyHooXUFRszksDdRlR9_82r0DuIM585DP45EA)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You shouldn't use paths `C:\Users\SalahGfx\Desktop\Password Generator Files\` - other user can put program in different folder and it will not work (even on other Windows).

You should use `sys.argv[0]` to get correct folder on any computer.
And then you can use `os.path.join(folder, "some_file.png")` to create path to images.

---

`#!/usr/bin/env python3` should be enought - you don't have to set `3.5.2` - and it will work even if someone has 3.4 or 3.6 but don't have 3.5.2.

---

You don't need

```
else:
    return
```

Code will work without it

---

```
except Exception:
    return
```

It is not good practice to skip exception.
It could print message in console (using print())
so you could run it in terminal and see more information about problem.

---

Method `exit()` should rathern has name `run()` because `app.exec_()` starts Qt framework - it runs its engine (its mainloop/event-loop).

Besides, you have this method but you don't use it - you run `sys.exit(app.exec_())` - but you could run `window.exit()`

---

You could read PEP8 - https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/

It suggests to use UpperCase names for classes - without underscore
ie. PasswordGenerator, InfoWindow.

Even Qt doesn't use underscore in class names.

Comment: I will put your advice under care, thank you so much for your time

Comment: A further suggestion -- use print to log the type of error that happened, then insert a bare 'raise' statement (which preserves the stack trace/traceback). This will help you debug. Read more on exceptions: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2052390/manually-raising-throwing-an-exception-in-python